# having trouble installing scalding

Tags: scala, sbt, classpath, slf4j, scalding

I'm installing Scalding and sbt on my system but running command sbt assembly gives the following error:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".

SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation

SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on AWS DynamoDB client. I resolved it by adding the following dependencies to maven pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.30</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.30</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.30</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

If you're not compiling, but just running binaries, download the [slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.30/slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar) and [slf4j-simple-1.7.30.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.7.30/slf4j-simple-1.7.30.jar) jars and put them on the classpath.